# Swift: how to more accurately detect if a symbol inside or outside of the wall?

Tags: swift, io

Map is drawn with text content like below:

```
#######..
#.....#..
#...#####
#...#@..#
#...##..#
#....#...
######...
```

`#`: wall

`.`: blank (use `@` as a special `.` on above)

Since there are two kinds of blank, inside and outside the wall. I need to figure them out separately.

The inside `.` will convert to 2, the outside `.` will convert to 0

By now, I'm using a method that search the four directions of each dot's (up, down, left, right), if all of them are `#`, the dot is inside wall.

First, convert each line to array `lines`

```
var wallCount = 0
        for i in 0...lines.count{
            let line = lines[i]

            // ignore first and last character
            for  j in 1...line.count-2 {

                let char = String(Array(line)[j])
                if char == "." {
                    var wallCount = 0
                    // left
                    var l = j
                    while (l >= 0) {
                        let lChar = String(Array(line)[l])
                        if(lChar == "#"){
                            wallCount += 1
                            break;
                        }
                        l -= 1
                    }

                    // and then...
                    // right
                    // up
                    // down
                }
            }
        }
```

It maybe not efficient, and it's ok in most cases, except in one case it's ineffective: from the map above, it figures that `@` is inside the wall. Since it has `#` in four directions, but actually it stands outside the wall.

How to improve the above code more efficient and accurate?

Thanks.

Comment: "It works, but it figures that @ is inside the wall"... Your definition of "works" is pretty interesting. I would recommend rephrasing the question and *ask how to solve this problem*.

Comment: @SimonForsberg post edited. Can give any idea about that? php, java, objective-c and swift are ok.

Answer (score 0):

### The idea

We can build a recursive function to look for a path from the hero to the border.

If such a path **exists** then the hero is **outside** of the walls.
Otherwise he's **inside** the walls.

The recursive function receives a `cell index` as paramenter along with the set of the visited indexes.

If this cell is on the **border** then the function returns `true`.
Otherwise it evaluates all the cells adjacents to current one that are **free** and **have not been visited**.

For each one of these cells the function is called **recursively** until a path to the border is found or all the cells have been visited.

### Code!

We need a proper way of representing and interacting with the Map.

I am going to use the Matrix struct described in [The Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Subscripts.html) and will add some customizations.

### The Matrix

```
struct Matrix {

    enum Cell: String {
        case wall = "#"
        case empty = "."
        case hero = "@"
    }

    struct Index: Hashable {
        let x, y: Int

        var adjacents: [Index] {
            return [Index(x: x - 1, y: y), Index(x: x + 1, y: y), Index(x: x, y: y - 1), Index(x: x, y: y + 1)]
        }
    }

    private let rows: Int, columns: Int
    private var grid: [Cell]

    init(rows: Int, columns: Int) {
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns
        grid = Array(repeating: .empty, count: rows * columns)
    }

    private func indexIsValid(index: Index) -> Bool {
        return indexIsValid(row: index.x, column: index.y)
    }

    private func indexIsValid(row: Int, column: Int) -> Bool {
        return row >= 0 && row < rows && column >= 0 && column < columns
    }

    subscript(row: Int, column: Int) -> Cell {
        get {
            assert(indexIsValid(row: row, column: column), "Index out of range")
            return grid[(row * columns) + column]
        }
        set {
            assert(indexIsValid(row: row, column: column), "Index out of range")
            grid[(row * columns) + column] = newValue
        }
    }

    var description: String {
        var res = ""
        for row in 0..<rows {
            for column in 0..<columns {
                res += self[row, column].rawValue
            }
            res += "\n"
        }
        return res
    }

    private func indexIsOnBorder(_ index: Index) -> Bool {
        return index.x == 0 || index.y == 0 || index.x == columns - 1 || index.y == rows - 1
    }

    func findPathToBorder(from index: Index,
                          visitedIndexes: inout Set<Index>) -> Bool {

        visitedIndexes.insert(index)
        if matrix.indexIsOnBorder(index) {
            return true
        }
        return index
            .adjacents // up, right, down, left
            .filter(indexIsValid) // which are inside the matrix
            .filter { matrix[$0.x, $0.y] == .empty } // are empty
            .filter { !visitedIndexes.contains($0) } // not visited yet
            .contains { adjacent in
                findPathToBorder(from: adjacent, visitedIndexes: &visitedIndexes)
            } // and are part of a path to the border
    }

}
```

### Populating the Matrix

```
var matrix = Matrix(rows: 7, columns: 9)
matrix[0, 0] = .wall
matrix[0, 1] = .wall
matrix[0, 2] = .wall
matrix[0, 3] = .wall
matrix[0, 4] = .wall
matrix[0, 5] = .wall
matrix[0, 6] = .wall

matrix[1, 0] = .wall
matrix[1, 6] = .wall

matrix[2, 0] = .wall
matrix[2, 4] = .wall
matrix[2, 5] = .wall
matrix[2, 6] = .wall
matrix[2, 7] = .wall
matrix[2, 8] = .wall

matrix[3, 0] = .wall
matrix[3, 4] = .wall
matrix[3, 5] = .hero
matrix[3, 8] = .wall

matrix[4, 0] = .wall
matrix[4, 4] = .wall
matrix[4, 5] = .wall
matrix[4, 8] = .wall

matrix[5, 0] = .wall
matrix[5, 5] = .wall

matrix[6, 0] = .wall
matrix[6, 1] = .wall
matrix[6, 2] = .wall
matrix[6, 3] = .wall
matrix[6, 4] = .wall
matrix[6, 5] = .wall

print(matrix.description)
```

Now you'll see this in the console

```
#######..
#.....#..
#...#####
#...#@..#
#...##..#
#....#...
######...
```

### Running our function

```
var visitedIndexes: Set<Matrix.Index> = []
let isHeroOutsideTheWalls = matrix.findPathToBorder(from: Matrix.Index(x: 3, y: 2), visitedIndexes: &visitedIndexes)

print(isHeroOutsideTheWalls) // true
```

Hope this helps.